# Меняется порядок элементов в массиве при передаче с сервера на клиент в формате json

Tags: php, javascript, json

Всем привет
Получаю из бд массив, отсортированный в нужном порядке.
Кодирую в json_encode и отправляю на клиент, однако в браузере порядок другой(во всех кроме сафари)
Смотрю массив до кодирования - правильный порядок, кодирую и отправляю - порядок уже другой

до

[image]

после
[image: после]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таком виде порядок сохранится

```
echo json_encode([[1=>1], [3=>3], [2=>2], [5=>5]]);
```

Comment: спасибо, так и сделаю

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле порядок не меняется. Порядок меняет парсер, встроенный в браузер. json не предусматривает сохранение порядка аттрибутов в объектах. Для этого существует ordered list. В таком виде порядок сохранится.

```
[
    {key: val}, 
    {key1:val1}
]
```

Приведу пример, чтобы показать, что порядок меняет браузер

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode([1=>1, 3=>3, 2=>2, 5=>5]);
```

Если посмотреть на ответ в формате raw (вкладка "ответ" в chrome dev tools), всё в том порядке, что я передал:

```
{"1":1,"3":3,"2":2,"5":5}
```

Но во вкладке "preview" или как у вас в "JSON". Парсер браузера изменил порядок.

```
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
5: 5
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но порядок даже не по ключу) 32-35-37-120264-118830...

Comment: да, действительно. Внес изменения в ответ